# python - keyerror when referencing array in object

Tags: python, arrays, string, object, keyerror

```
if json.loads(line)['index'] > 1:
    pprint(json.loads(line))
    if json.loads(line)['transactions'][0]['recipient'] != json.loads(prev_line)['transactions'][0]['recipient'] and ...
```

This is my console output and error:

```
Eamons-MBP:blockchain-clone eamonwhite$ python3 pytest.py
{'index': 2,
 'previous_hash': 'aa097e7a6946fa1a034d1330ed1ce3b425f74a071e8b09499647706270684649',
 'proof': 888273,
 'timestamp': 1514402104.78347,
 'transactions': [{'amount': 1,
                   'recipient': 'a7cfdfcc523b453284281102b87a1dfe',
                   'sender': '0'}]}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pytest.py", line 14, in <module>
    if json.loads(line)['transactions'][0]['recipient'] != json.loads(prev_line)['transactions'][0]['recipient'] and ...
KeyError: 'transactions'
```

The object being output is immediately is just the starting line and you can see that it has a `transactions` key which is storing an array with one object in it. How do I reference it?

Comment: make sure to check the content of both `line` and `prev_line` json (also if your `add ...` is having such reference of "transactions")

Comment: ahh i think its prev_line one sec

Comment: u were right @MoinuddinQuadri fill out an answer if you want